# Change ONLY the color of the plot for z = 0 with surf, possible?

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to change the classical blue color for the surface on the plane at z = 0? I would like to change ONLY the blue with a transparent colour or white.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Perhaps show the code for the plot, which you already have, as a sample, so we could modify it.

Comment: Thanks @StefanKottwitz. The code is very simple:
\addplot3[surf] file{DATA.dat};